# From $a_{n+1}= \frac {2n+1}{n+1}a_n$ to $a_n$ case 3

Tags: real-analysis, induction

> Find and prove by induction an explicit formula for $a_n$ if $a_1=1$ and, for $n \geq 1$,
>   $$a_{n+1}= \frac {2n+1}{n+1}a_n$$

I am checking the pattern:

$$a_1=1$$
$$a_2=\frac{3}{2}$$
$$a_3=\frac{5}{2}$$
$$a_4=\frac {5\cdot7}{8}$$
$$a_5=\frac {7\cdot9}{8}$$
$$a_6= \frac{7 \cdot 9 \cdot 11}{16 \cdot 3}$$
$$a_7= \frac {7 \cdot 9 \cdot 11 \cdot 13}{16 \cdot 3 \cdot 7}$$

I just cant see any pattern.

Comment: Do not simplify the ratios and you will see the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{(n+1)!a_{n+1}}{(2n+1)!!}= \frac {2n+1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{(n+1)!a_n}{(2n+1)!!}$$

$$\frac{(n+1)!a_{n+1}}{(2n+1)!!}= \frac{n!a_n}{(2n-1)!!}$$

So

$$\frac{n!a_n}{(2n-1)!!}=\frac{1!a_1}{1!!}=1$$

$$a_n=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!}\cdot\frac{(2n)!!}{2^nn!}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!n!}=\frac{1}{2^n}\binom{2n}{n}$$

The induction proof is easy.

Comment: What is $!!$ ? Sorry if its a silly question, but I don't know it yet :)

Comment: Just like $n!$, but only multiply those integers of the same parity. $10!!=10\times 8\times 6\times 4\times 2$ and $9!!=9\times 7\times 5\times 3\times 1$.

Comment: That was beautiful solution.